# Getting a Listbox Variable to a Label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, label

I'm having problems getting the listbox info to a label without labels overlaping each other, I tried to use ".configure()" and "label['text'] =" to change the output of the Label but the old info remains in the screen

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('1000x500')

lbx_info = ['short frase', 'medium sentence', 'the longest sentence in the list']
lbl_bg = ['#ff0000', '#ffff00', '#00cc00']

lbx = tk.Listbox(window, font='Arial 20', bd=10)
for e in lbx_info:
    lbx.insert(tk.END, e)
lbx.place(x=0, y=0)


def show(pos):
    name_lbl = tk.Label(window, font='Arial 16')
    name_lbl.configure(text=f'Nome: {lbx_info[pos[0]]}', bg=f'{lbl_bg[pos[0]]}')
    name_lbl.place(x=500, y=0)


lbx.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda m: show(lbx.curselection()))
window.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Try moving the `name_lbl = tk.Label(window, font='Arial 16')` outside of the function.

Comment: `show` creates a new label every time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

As @BryanOakley pointed out, each time the function is called you create a new `Label`. The easiest fix is just to move the `name_lbl = tk.Label(...)` outside of the function. It also wouldn't be a bad idea to move the `name_lbl.place(...)` ouside of the function as well.

So your code should look like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('1000x500')

lbx_info = ['short frase', 'medium sentence', 'the longest sentence in the list']
lbl_bg = ['#ff0000', '#ffff00', '#00cc00']

lbx = tk.Listbox(window, font='Arial 20', bd=10)
for e in lbx_info:
    lbx.insert(tk.END, e)
lbx.place(x=0, y=0)


name_lbl = tk.Label(window, font='Arial 16')
name_lbl.place(x=500, y=0)
def show(pos):
    name_lbl.configure(text=f'Nome: {lbx_info[pos[0]]}', bg=f'{lbl_bg[pos[0]]}')


lbx.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda m: show(lbx.curselection()))
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: wow i feel so dumb for not seeing it, thanks for the help guys